# How to implement TikTok API User Access Token Management v2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client, tiktok-api

I'm trying to update a TikTok API integration, specifically, the *User Access Token Management* part, which has recently been updated to V2.

My application is a Ruby on Rails app, and I'm encountering an error when trying to fetch an access token using an authorization code.

Here's the V1 code that is working :

```rb
def access_token_from(code)
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      method: :post,
      url: API_V1_BASE_URL + ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT +
      "?client_key=#{Rails.application.credentials.tiktok_client_key}" +
      "&client_secret=#{Rails.application.credentials.tiktok_client_secret}" +
      "&code=#{code}" +
      '&grant_type=authorization_code'
    )

    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
```

And here's the updated non-working code :

```rb
def manage_token_request(grant_type, params)
    url = API_V2_BASE_URL + ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT
    payload = {
      client_key: CLIENT_KEY,
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      grant_type: grant_type
    }
    headers = {
      content_type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      cache_control: "no-cache",
    }

    if params[:code].present?
      payload.merge({ code: params[:code], redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI })
    elsif params[:refresh_token].present?
      payload.merge({ refresh_token: params[:refresh_token] })
    end

    RestClient.post url, payload, headers
  end

  def access_token_from(code)
    response = manage_token_request(:authorization_code, { code: code })

    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
```

The response I got by calling the API through this call is this :

```json
{
 "error"=>"invalid_request",
 "error_description"=>"The request parameters are malformed.",
 "log_id"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't get more details on the expected format of the parameters.

I've been trying tweaking everything but still got the same The request parameters are malformed. response.
Note that executing the call on Postman works fine.

Does anyone have already made a RoR integration of that part of the TikTok API?

Comment: Am I right you asked for this API https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/oauth-user-access-token-management ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that part @VasilyKolesnikov.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer bellow? Was it helpful? @Donatien

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably that `:authorization_code` is a Symbol but must be a String. Try to convert it (grant_type.to_s) before pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't change anything. Still got the same error.